# Google App Scripting Progress Bar

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a progress bar in Google app scripting , which when some one click a button (Go) it will be automatically, slowly go to start to end . Something you see in Firefox download window. 
 this is my code.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var progressPanel = app.loadComponent("progressbar_auto");
  var gobutton =app.getElementById("go_btn");

  var go_btn_handler =app.createServerHandler("updateProgressbar");
  go_btn_handler.addCallbackElement(gobutton);
  gobutton.addClickHandler(go_btn_handler)


  app.add(progressPanel);
  return app;
}
//function time(i){
//    Utilities.sleep(5);
//  }
function updateProgressbar(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication()

  for(var i =1 ; i < 250 ; i++ ){

    app.getElementById("progress").setWidth(i + 'px');
    time();
  }
 Logger.log(i);
  return app;

}
```

But according to this code for loop will execute very speedy & ,progress bar completed very quick . Is there any way to slow this.

You can find the my application here.

https://sites.google.com/a/macros/dewdynamics.net/exec?service=AKfycbztKB_ljMBGi_55RrK_DH3x_pRZQ993bDoAHSsxDA

Is there any way to add a slide bar , to control the progress bar. Something we can do in php or HTML 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a real way to do a progress bar on Apps Script.

There's some workarounds though. You can add multiple handlers to the same button, and in each one, with a different sleep time, you can update the GUI many times. Or, as most do, show an endless progress gif animation in a client handler (for instant feedback) and after your second handler finishes, a ServerHandler where you actually do the work, you hide the image and return the results.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions ..I 'll try the animation gif in client handler .

Comment: How would that work Henrique? What do you mean "multiple handlers"? Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: @Trevor well, just add them:  `btn.addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2)`, assuming you know how to create handlers: `handler1 = app.createServerHandler('functionA')`. Anyway, this answer is very old, HtmlService is probably a better idea if a real progress bar is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use HtmlServices for this. Just try it:
 [Click Here](http://caja.appspot.com/#examples/jquery-progressbar.html)

You can use jquery to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: to get the status of scripts running server side, you need to store progress to the cache. Then the client side can call a server-side function to retrieve it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution by storing data in the cache on the server side and reading the cache on the client side as suggested by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9842934/greg).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSXWQ.png)

[Video](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1gpWkkv0Nk2UyjlpfLf3hrgyXeh3dnHij)

Caching progress data server side

```
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();

async function updateCacheProgress(current, total, student) {

    // cache for 10 seconds
    cache.put("total", total, 10);      
    cache.put("current", current, 10);  
    cache.put("student", student, 10);  
}
```

Script on client side

```
window.addEventListener('load', getUpdatedProcess);

function updateProgress(data) {
  
  console.log('#student: ' + data.student)
  console.log('#current: ' + data.current)
  console.log('#total: ' + data.total)
  

  var ProgressBar    = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var Progress       = document.getElementById('progress');
  var ProgressStatus = document.getElementById('progressStatus');

  var percent = 0.1

  percent = data.current / data.total *100;
  percent = percent.toFixed(1);

  Progress.style.width = percent + '%';
  Progress.innerText =  percent + '%';
  ProgressStatus.innerHTML = data.student + ` (${data.current} of ${data.total})` 

  if(percent < 100) getUpdatedProcess()

}

function getUpdatedProcess() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgress).getProgress();
}
```

Apps Script that retrieves stored cache executed via client

```
function getProgress() {
    var total = cache.get("total");
    var current = cache.get("current");
    var student = cache.get("student");

    return {total: total, current: current, student: student}
}
```

Client HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: 'Arial';
      }

      #progressBar {
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: silver;
      }

      #progress {
        width: 0%; 
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 32px;
        text-align: center;

        color: white;
        background-color: green;
      }

      #progressStatus {

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


  <div id="progressBar"> 
    <div id="progress"></div>
  </div> 
  <br><br>

  <div id="progressStatus"><?= student ?> (<?= progress ?>)</div>
  </body>
</html>
```