# How to display a progressbar in a Google Spreadsheet while a script is running

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to display a progressbar in a Google Spreadsheet while a script is running (until it is finished)?
Something like JQuery progressbar would be fine, but on which selector?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Mydiv').progressbar({value: false} );
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Scripting Progress Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651493/google-app-scripting-progress-bar)

Comment: @user1989 I'm using a Google spreadsheet, not App

Comment: What is Google spreadsheet then?

Answer (score 1):

the script you have is ok but if you want something intricate or complex, it will calculate percentages while the script is running

**the CSS:**

```
#progressbox {
border: 1px solid #0099CC;
padding: 1px;
position:relative;
width:400px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 10px;
display:none;
text-align:left;
}
#progressbar {
height:20px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #003333;
width:1%;
}
#statustxt {
top:3px;
left:50%;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
color: #000000;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var options = {
            target:   '#output',
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,
            uploadProgress: OnProgress, //upload progress callback
            success:       afterSuccess,
            resetForm: true  
        };

     $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);           
            return false;
        });
});
```

The function below captures the arguments passed by form plugin, changing the width and text of progressbar real-time.

```
function OnProgress(event, position, total, percentComplete)
{
    //Progress bar
    progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
    statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
    if(percentComplete>50)
        {
            statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50%
        }
}
```

@ref: http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php

this deals with image uploads, but you can substitute it for scripts running in the background.